# iOS frame rate drop without maximum device utilization

Tags: ios, performance, graphics, gpu

I am making an iOS game using Unity. I am testing some shaders that I have made for the game, and in some cases the device will run at under 30 FPS but not have 100% device utilization.

Sometimes a test will start at a higher device utilization %, and then over time go lower, even though the test is simply rendering a plane with a material on it.

For example, a shader test I just ran on an iPad 4:
Device utilization 85%
Renderer utilization 85%
Tiler utilization 1%
Core Animation Frames Per Second 12

This test is using barely any CPU, and is only rendering 4 triangles (2 big planes covering the screen).

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening? Usually the renderer utilization goes up to 100%... pretty stumped, being a graphics rookie.

Thanks for the help!